# dispatch_async update variable crash - thread safety

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

When I run the following code multiple times app crashes at the line :

res.append(i)

The error is  fatal error: UnsafeMutablePointer.destroy with negative count 
or
 pointer being freed was not allocated *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Is it not correct to update a global variable inside dispatch_async?

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var result = Array<Int>()


func method(completion: (inner: () throws -> String)->Void){
    let group:dispatch_group_t = dispatch_group_create();
    let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
    var res = Array<Int>()
    for i in 0..<4 {
        dispatch_group_async(group,queue){
            res.append(i)
            print(res)
            print("Block\(i)");                
            var s = 0
            for k in 0..<1000 {
                s = 2+3
            }
            print("Block\(i)End");



        }
    }

    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    print("All background tasks are done!!");
    print(res)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.method() { (inner: () throws -> String) -> Void in
        do {
            let res = try inner()
            print(res)
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: basic multi threading issue -- unless specifically mentioned DONT assume an object is thread safe and don't update from multiple threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, `Array` is not thread safe, so when write to array, should ensure `atomic`.

So you can add heigh performance lock ： dispatch_semaphore_t.

```
func method(completion: (inner: () throws -> String)->Void){
    //  add lock
    let lock: dispatch_semaphore_t = dispatch_semaphore_create(1)
    let group:dispatch_group_t = dispatch_group_create();
    let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
    var res = Array<Int>()
    for i in 0 ..< 5 {
        dispatch_group_async(group,queue){
            // lock
            dispatch_semaphore_wait(lock, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
            res.append(i)
            // unlock
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(lock)
            var s = 0
            for k in 0..<1000 {
                s = 2+3
            }
        }
    }

    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    print("All background tasks are done!!");
    print(res)
}
```

But be careful, if your async task is not time-consuming operation like the above, don't use multi-thread, because thread schedule is time-consuming and could lead to performance loss.

Comment: Thank you. This was just sample code. So then if I am accessing lot of global variables inside dispatch_async what is the best option? Should I use NSOperationQueue?

Comment: I not sure whether a lot of variables that you mention is multi-thread safe. If not, there are generally two kinds of processing way: 1. use concurrent queue + lock like the above 2. use serial queue can ensure atomic too. Or you need use other plan according to your demand. You can read this series of article https://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1, maybe helpful.

Comment: And this Swift version https://www.raywenderlich.com/79149/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-1